# Simulating pinches on iPad-Simulator

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, pinch

I'm currently trying to implement the handling of (2-finger-)pinches on an iPad display. Doing so I came across the problem that the fingers (represented by by two grey circles in the iPhone-simulator) won't show up in the simulator for iPad. Even though it is still possible to simulate pinches it's sometimes very hard to do so without seeing the fingers and it's even impossible to drag the fingers to a location of where the pinches should happen.

Is there a secret setting etc. to enable those grey circles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the grey circles to work in iOS Simulator 5.1 for iPad, you have to set the scale to 75% (Cmd-2) or 50% (Cmd-3).  Why?  I don't know.  Seems like a bug.

Comment: Great help, works perfectly after scaling! Thank you very much :)

Comment: This is not reproduced with iOS Simulator 10.0, they probably fixed it :)

Answer (score 118):

You should be able to see them if you hold down the Option key while clicking the mouse in the area you wish to "pinch". Also if you press press Shift-Option it will lock the two "fingers" positions relative to each other.

1. Place the pointer where you want the pinch to occur.
2. Hold down the Option key.
3. Move the circles that represent finger touches to the start position.
4. Move the center of the pinch target by holding down the Shift key, moving the circles to the desired center position, and releasing the Shift key.
5. Hold down the mouse button, move the circles to the end position, and release the Option key.

via [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS/InteractingwithiOSandwatchOS.html)

Comment: I edited my initial post with some more direction. I took these steps right off the apple website.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort :) but it's still not working ... verrry odd :/